# $_REQUEST works but $_POST does not

Tags: php, html, forms, http

I have a HTML form with post method

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/scrollbar.js'> </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/string.js'> </script>

    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='styles/defaults.css'/>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='styles/header.css'/>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='styles/content.css'/>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='styles/preview.css'/>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='styles/key-value.css'/>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='styles/notice.css' />  
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles/footer.css' />

    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
</head>
<body>
<nav id='navigation' class='alternative'>
    <section id='logo'> <a href='/.'>im</a> </section>
</nav>  <div class='content alternative'>

<form class='A4 page' method='post' action='includes/process-book-submission.php?action=add&mid=-1&isbn=0309211794&quality=New&scheduled=Fri Jan 15 2016&comments=&price=77.11&extras=&deal=sell&pendings=YES&seller=1'>
    <table class='im key-value' id='preview'>
        <caption> 
            <h1>Item's Information Review</h1> 
            <small>(You can always make changes in the future)</small>
        </caption>
        <tbody>
            <tr> 
                <td><strong>Title</strong></td> 
                <td id='title'> <label>Approaches for Ecosystem Services Valuation for the Gulf of Mexico After the Deepwater Horizon Oil Spill: Interim Report</label> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Authors(s)</strong></td> 
                <td id='authors'> <label>Committee on the Effects of the Deepwater Horizon Mississippi Canyon-252 Oil Spill on Ecosystem Services in the Gulf of Mexico, Ocean Studies Board, Division on Earth and Life Studies, National Research Council</label> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td><strong>ISBN</strong></td> 
                <td id='isbn'> <label>0309211794<label> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td><strong>Book Condition</strong></td> 
                <td id='quality'> <label>New<label> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td><strong>Available Starting</strong></td> 
                <td id='accessible'> <label>January 15th, 2016<label> </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td><strong>Available For</strong></td> 
                <td> </label>Sell</label> </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Price</strong></td> 
                <td id='price'> <label>$77.11<label> </td> 
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><strong>Include My Pending List</strong></td>
                <td>
                    <label>YES</label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td><strong>Comments</strong></td> 
                <td></td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style='text-align: center; padding: 25px 0px;'>
        <button class='im2' onclick="location.href='../index.php'">Cancel</button>
        <button class='im2'>Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then I submit the page and go to page.php. If I `print_r $_REQUEST` or if I print_r $_GET these two work, but when I `print_r $_POST` it is empty, can anybody please explain what is happening, why I am not able to use $_POST even when I specify method='post' in my form

Comment: `Some code`?? Is it really like that?

Comment: And $_GET? Is it empty too?

Comment: @Hassan there is a reason why I did not post the code; it is too long. However, if you think it is necessary I can include it. But once again, I don't believe is necessary as I have tested by printing to screen

Comment: @Gacci please include it.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta Thanks a lot. Actually $_GET works as well!

Comment: Then for some reason that we can help you to understand only looking at the code you are sending the form via GET and not POST. How do you send the form? Do you use ajax maybe?

Comment: @Lelio Faeita I just posted the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted is not a form but just a link to another page.

You are passing to it some data after the ? In the url that correctly you will find in the target page via $_get.

To use a form and post method you have to remove all the info after the ? In the url and replace each of the variable=value pair with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="thevariable" value="thevalue">
```

Where each time thevariable and thename are one of the pair you want to post.

Then you will be able to access the data via $_post

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use redirect instead of submit

change

```
<button class='im2'>Continue</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="continue" name="submit">
```

the other way is to trigger form.submit event on button click.

Edit:

You get variables via `$_GET` because you set them in action URL. 
Also there are no inputs to be send via post. So you need create some via `<input>` html tag or `<textarea>` etc.. pay attention you need to set the name attribute for these html tags to be properly send to server.

example:

put this code `<input type="text" name="isbn" value="0309211794">` inside your `<form></form>` with code I posted above and click `submit`

Comment: I don't think so. The reason is because as I mentioned, if I print to screen $_REQUEST or $_GET the info is actually there. Now, when I print $_POST is shows it as empty

Comment: Form is not posted it is redirected there is no POST request created when you redirect user. Before you write "I don't think so" check it..

Comment: $_REQUEST and $_GET are there because you set them in form action, you can create `<a href="includes/process-book-submission.php?action=add&mid=-1&isbn=0309211794&quality=New&scheduled=Fri Jan 15 2016&comments=&price=77.11&extras=&deal=sell&pendings=YES&seller=1">test</a>` and you will also have them.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I am not trying to fight with you. I am trying to be helped. I tried and it posts the button. Seems like I am getting confused about how forms work.

Comment: Ok so to make it as simple as possible use this code: `<form class='A4 page' method='post' action='includes/process-book-submission.php'>
<input type="text" name="isbn" value="0309211794">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>` and check what `$_POST` contains

Answer (score 1):

Your form don't have **input** fields, that's why $_POST is empty.

You don't send anything to server through POST, and your $_GET not empty because you pass parameters at url in action parameter of form,
for the same reason $_REQUEST not empty too.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I mistakenly thought that using an url also represented posting a key/value pair.